Network frequently dropping while playing online games on just one device - possible hardware issue?
Basically what the title says. It started happening about a week ago. It happens at random moments so it is hard to consistently replicate. It could happen even 10 minutes or it could not happen for 4-5 hours. But it definitely happens multiple times a day because at this point I have just been keeping a game open for a few hours, even while not playing, to see if I keep disconnecting and it does in fact keep happening daily.
Few days before it started happening I got a new M.2 SSD, could this in someway cause issues? It got installed in my 2nd M.2 slot, bit further away from the CPU. The M.2 is a SAMSUNG 990 PRO 2 TB SSD. I just read online that this slot specifically is PCIe 3.0 and the SSD is 4.0. Is this a problem other than limited speed? Could this in any way affect my network? Keep in mind the issue only happens on this device. Whenever the internet drops out my Wifi still works on other devices and a laptop for example connected with cable to same modem also still works.
These are my specs:
Windows
Gigabyte B660 DS3H DDR4
Intel i5-12400
RTX 4070 Super
32GB RAM
These are the things I have already tried:

New network card installed
New ethernet cable
Reset modem
New modem/router at home
Updated network drivers
Fresh install of Windows
Memtest with bootable USB -> no errors
Called with ISP to check for possible dropouts or errors -> no issues
Tried the same games on a different device, used the same cable -> no issues
DNS flush
Disabled motherboard network adapter after installing new one
Checked event viewer for logs -> no errors/warnings when losing connection

Something I have not tried is taking out the M.2 again, because I feel like adding this M.2 is literally the only thing that changed around the time the issue showed up. Reason I haven't tried it yet is just because I never really changed parts myself.

forget about it being the M2 This wouldn't affect network on its own but the entire system would freeze if there were ssd issues, but do open an admin command prompt and type sfc /scannow to check if any system files have been changed. report back

@JohnnyVegas I figured it probably wasn't the M2 but I am just trying to rule out everything since I feel like I already tried pretty much everything. I just did the command and it said it fixed corrupt files and when I went to check the log that it mentioned I could only find one file was corrupt and got repaired: DEPLOY [Pnp] Corrupt file: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\bthmodem.sys

Its not entirely impossible there is some kinda of PCIe sharing going on between the network adapter and the M.2 slot. Its unlikely however and you tried with a different network adapter anyway. You've already tried alot of things, making it look like your computer might not be the problem. It might be a network problem. Try seeing if the problem shows itself outside of gaming by pinging some server. Check if internal network traffic is affected as well. Check if you are still connected and have an internal IP when the issue arises.

so - have you used event viewer? play a game to see if the network drops out. if it does make a note of the system time (use alt tab to switch back to the desktop) then go through event viewer looking at the exact time the dropout happened.

@JohnnyVegas I did check event viewer a few times and there's never anything there at the time of the disconnect. Not even minutes later. Should have probably mentioned that I had already tried this

@Silbee I have already tried it for a bit outside of gaming, was pinging 8.8.8.8 for hours and had no issues/drops. I also just tried having a game open while pinging the internal IP and kept pinging it even during disconnect. It never shows an issue. The IP also doesn't change during the disconnect, I checked with ipconfig. Compared to the ping to 8.8.8.8 it says "Request timed out" 5 times

event viewer shows everything - you need to know what you are looking for - you need to send a screenshot of event viewer in custom views/administrative events at the time of the dropout

I also need to know the network card types you are using, along with the router

@JohnnyVegas Screenshot of the event viewer: https://imgur.com/a/2MlCLnP
The disconnect happened at 22:22 and as you can see there are no new logs listed, the screenshot itself was taken about 10 minutes later. I did in fact make sure to refresh but no logs showed up. Then my network cards are the built-in one from my motherboard Gigabyte B660 DS3H DDR4 and the new one that I have added is the tp-link tx201 2.5 gigabit. And for the router you mentioned, I only have a modem from my ISP. Which is a F@st3896LG (from Telenet, ISP in Belgium) and I am guessing the name is just a ISP specific thing

It also took me a while to be able to provide the info since this time it took a few hours for me to replicate the disconnect again. So as you can see it does happen very randomly because during the day it kept happening every 30 minutes and then suddenly it did not happen for hours

can you disable uPnP on the modem and see if you get another disconnect?

@JohnnyVegas I checked and uPnP was never enabled on the modem

There are no further things to investigate, sorry.
